# Could not load stylesheets based on days of week

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

How can we load different stylesheets based on days of week.I have written the js ,but it's not working.

```
  var d = new Date();
        var weekday = new Array(7);
        weekday[0] = "Sunday";
        weekday[1] = "Monday";
        weekday[2] = "Tuesday";
        weekday[3] = "Wednesday";
        weekday[4] = "Thursday";
        weekday[5] = "Friday";
        weekday[6] = "Saturday";
        var n = weekday[d.getDay()];
        document.writeln('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Styles/' + n +'.css">');
```

My stylesheets lies in a folder named 'Styles' inside the project folder.Could someone help me please.

Comment: your code seems ok

Comment: Is there any format for giving folder name in href

Comment: its case sensitive - if that's what mean

Comment: try removing the first 2 dots and forward slash see if that helps? or do you need to go back a directory

Comment: my stylesheets lies inside a folder named 'Styles' inside the project folder.

Comment: post the html also, where you have use this javascript.

Answer (score 2):

You are simply appending your file to the body and not informing the DOM that there is a new stylesheet file.

Try this:

```
var d = new Date();
        var weekday = new Array(7);
        weekday[0] = "Sunday";
        weekday[1] = "Monday";
        weekday[2] = "Tuesday";
        weekday[3] = "Wednesday";
        weekday[4] = "Thursday";
        weekday[5] = "Friday";
        weekday[6] = "Saturday";
        var n = weekday[d.getDay()];


    var link = document.createElement( "link" );
        link.href = "../Styles/" + n +".css";
        link.type = "text/css";
        link.rel = "stylesheet";
        link.media = "screen,print";

document.getElementsByTagName( "head" )[0].appendChild( link );
```

If possible make sure this loads before your body tag to prevent an issue called [FOUC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content)

Let me know if this solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Since the question is tagged with `asp.net`, why not do it from code behind programatically. With this method the sylesheet is already on the page when it's loaded by the browser.

```
//create a new htmllink
HtmlLink link = new HtmlLink();

//set the correct attributes
link.Attributes.Add("rel", "stylesheet");
link.Attributes.Add("type", "text/css");

//set the correct stylesheet url based on the weekday name
link.Href = "/Styles/" + DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek + ".css";

//add the htmllink to the page header
this.Page.Header.Controls.Add(link);
```